# Allow login as any user from group by sudoers

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo, user-permissions

I'd like to add a `/etc/sudoers` rule to allow any user from group `admin` to login as a user from group `users`.

*Example:*

In group `admin` I have: `alan` and `smith`. In group `users`: `anna`, `mike`. And other users: `stephen`, `nick`.

`alan` and `smith` can do this:

```
sudo su - anna
sudo su - mike
```

But the can't do this:

```
sudo su -
sudo su - root
sudo su - stephen
```

I vainly tried something like this:

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/su - %users
```

Any ideas?

---

P.S. it would be ideal if complied with one more dependency:

`alan` is also in `users` group and `smith` can't do:

```
sudo su - alan
```

because `alan` is in `admin` group.

Comment: Don't use `sudo su`, use `sudo -u alan`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you actually want or need `su` for your use case. What you seem to want, is for a certain group of users to be able to arbitrarily assume the identity of any user in a specific other group. You just need sudoers for that:

```
%admin ALL=(%users) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

The above sudoers rule means all users in the `admin` group can run *any* command *as* any user in the `users` group via `sudo -u <user> <command>`.

If you wanted to you could limit the commands the admins users could run as another user you replace `ALL` at the end with something more specific. See `man sudoers` for more on that.

To get a ~login shell for the given `users` group user, instead of using `su`, an *admin* could do:

```
sudo -u anna /bin/bash -il
```

---

A note on `su` (man su):

> The su command is used to become another user during a login session.

`su` always prompts for the password of the user you are logging as, *except* for the case where the invoking user is root. `sudo su - [user]` does not prompt for a password because you elevate to root (via sudo), then exec `su - [user]` to start a new login session. But if you don't want to elevate the sudoer to root, the sudoer needs to know the password of the user they want to `su` as, defeating the purpose of using `sudo` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You just can't use the "%users" because that would mean a linux group, not a sudoers variable.

You can do something like the following:

```
Cmnd_Alias      SWITCH_USERS = /bin/su - anna, /bin/su - mike
%admin      ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: SWITCH_USERS
```

If you are creating two groups admin/users in the system only for this matter, you may want to create sudoers users Aliases (so you only have to keep track of sudoers files) In my personal opinion, is best to use sudoers options for sudo, and system groups for files/dirs related permissions (but this is **my opinion, not a must**)

Sudoers manual is a little bit difficult to understand in some topics. Here you have a good guide (with examples) that may help you editing your sudoers file: [how to edit the sudoers file](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file-on-ubuntu-and-centos)

I think the most useful you have to keep in mind for what you are trying to accomplish is: if you add a complete command in sudoers (with all options and parameter, it should be run that way, so, "/bin/su -" won't work if you specify a username after the command (see my example) You can negate with NOEXEC: a command you want to disallow by any mean in sudo, and always use "visudo" to edit /etc/sudoers, that checks the syntax.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But for me `Cmnd_Alias` is not enough. In my system I have about 200 users with various privilages and groups. I have one last idea. I'd create a script as root with one argument (user name). In this script I'll check if users is in group 'users'. If yes, I call `su - $1`. And in `/etc/sudoers` I'll add `%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/myscript *`